# Place SQL Window over non-Continuous Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table in SQL Server:

| KEY_ID | DEMAND | DAY | STOCKS | SORT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5.263 | 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 6 | 0 | 1 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 7 | 0 | 2 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 8 | 0 | 3 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 9 | 0 | 4 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 10 | 0 | 5 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 11 | 2 | 6 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 12 | 0 | 7 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 13 | 0 | 8 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 14 | 0 | 9 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 15 | 0 | 10 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 16 | 0 | 11 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 17 | 0 | 12 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 18 | 0 | 13 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 19 | 1 | 14 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 1 | 0 | 20 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 2 | 0 | 21 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 3 | 0 | 22 |
| 10 | 5.263 | 4 | 0 | 23 |

I'd like to partition the table every time there is a change in the `STOCKS` column. For example, the first partition would include days 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10. The second partition would include 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, and 18 etc. The goal is to sum the demand column for each partition, but I can't figure out how to write the `PARTITION BY` clause to recognize the various "buckets".

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using window funtion `SUM() OVER()` to mark the group of days based on `STOCKS` column

```
with cte as (
  SELECT *, SUM(STOCKS) OVER(ORDER BY SORT) AS cumulative_STOCKS
  FROM mytable t
)
select MAX(STOCKS) AS STOCKS, SUM(DEMAND) AS SUM_DEMAND
from cte
GROUP BY cumulative_STOCKS
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WjdvBSzI)